# How do i find the most used values in an element of panda

Tags: python, pandas

```
10.223.157.186 - - [15/Jul/2009:14:58:59 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 202
10.223.157.186 - - [15/Jul/2009:14:58:59 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209
10.223.157.186 - - [15/Jul/2009:15:50:35 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 9157
10.211.47.159 - - [10/Aug/2009:20:52:19 -0700] "GET /assets/js/lowpro.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
10.216.113.172 - - [12/Aug/2009:06:04:50 -0700] "GET /release-schedule/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9306
10.216.113.172 - - [12/Aug/2009:06:04:50 -0700] "GET /release-schedule/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9306
10.216.113.172 - - [12/Aug/2009:06:04:52 -0700] "GET /displaytitle.php?id=10 HTTP/1.1" 200 10234
10.216.113.172 - - [12/Aug/2009:06:04:52 -0700] "GET /displaytitle.php?id=10 HTTP/1.1" 200 10234
```

Lets say i have a column have all the host which means (10.223.157.186) and I want to find the most frequent used host.

```
result = Mainpanda['host'].mode()
print("Mode:\n",result)
```

I know by using host can find them but somehow it only display the top 1, I need to put them in to a list from 1 to the N
may someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a single column as string, first [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the IP, then use [`mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html):

```
result = Mainpanda['host'].str.extract(r'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)', expand=False).mode()
```

Output:

```
0    10.216.113.172
Name: host, dtype: object
```

If you want the top N, with the counts, use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
N = 10
result = (Mainpanda['host']
          .str.extract(r'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)', expand=False)
          .value_counts().head(10)
         )
```

Output:

```
10.216.113.172    4
10.223.157.186    3
10.211.47.159     1
...
Name: host, dtype: int64
```

If you want only a list of IPs:

```
N = 10
result = (Mainpanda['host']
          .str.extract(r'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)', expand=False)
          .value_counts().index[:N].tolist()
         )
```

Output:

```
['10.216.113.172', '10.223.157.186', '10.211.47.159', ...]
```

Comment: sorry i didn't make that specific I already have the host column in that column, I need the host listed there are 12000 host in that data frame I need to sort them there are 10 most used ones into a list

Comment: Have you checked the second part of my answer? (if you already have the host, just skip the `extract` part)

Comment: Oh ok I got that thanks sir/ ma'am any hint about addding the result to a string list?